# User vandalizing his own posts

Tags: discussion, status-completed, vandalism

[This guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/156796/langali) edited several of his posts, replacing everything with the word "test."

[Manual Transactional Service and DAO layer for JPA with Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812262/manual-transactional-service-and-dao-layer-for-jpa-with-spring)
[BindException/Too many file open while using HttpClient under load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914218/bindexception-too-many-file-open-while-using-httpclient-under-load)
[How should I design a plugin system in a layered Java EE Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129442/how-should-i-design-a-plugin-system-in-a-layered-java-ee-application)
[Running a Scala Script with external dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6350876/running-a-scala-script-with-external-dependencies)

I rollback to older versions of the posts. Why would someone do that? Should I report him to a moderator?

Comment: Rolling back is good. Flagging for mod attention is usually good too, but by posting here, it should get plenty of mod attention.

Comment: Perhaps he is testing if we would react to it?

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. This has been attended to (forgot to update this last night).